# sqoop : Pull data to hive table with extra columns

Tags: hive, hiveql, sqoop

I need to pull records from a `MySQL` table with n columns and store them in hive with extra columns. Is there any way in `sqoop` to perform it?

**Example:**

MySQL table has the following fields `id, name, place`. And,

Hive table structure is `id, name, place and contact number(null)`.

So when performing sqoop, I want to add an extra column `contact number` in hive as (null).

Comment: Did you try the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify it in the by using `--query` option in `sqoop` and **select** the extra column with `NULL AS`.

```
sqoop import \
  --query 'SELECT id, name, place, NULL AS contact_number FROM mysql_table'
  --connect jdbc:mysql://mysql.example.com/sqoop \
  --Any other options
```